# What is the point of creating a thread for a GUI if java automatically creates an AWT thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example, in java it is recommended that a thread be created for a GUI however given that an AWT thread is created which handles events and responds to them, the user created GUI thread would do nothing much as it passes much of the work over to the AWT thread, so what is the point of creating the user generated GUI thread in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by "user created GUI thread"?

Comment: `it is recommended that a thread be created for a GUI`  I haven't see this recommended.  Can you explain your source?  Give an example?

Comment: You may be confusing something. Most UI frameworks are single-threaded and not thread-safe. It is often recommended to put expensive or blocking work on a "background" thread to avoid monopolizing the UI thread. Otherwise such work leads to an unresponsive (i.e. frozen) UI because said UI thread can't perform any of its UI-related duties.

Comment: So the user thread handles UI, for example resizing components  while the AWT thread created automatically handles events created by the component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GUI thread does nothing much, why have a GUI?  :)

According to my understanding, it's not a question of dividing the *amount* of work, more a question of dividing the work by it's nature.

Comment: Given that the AWT thread handles all events from all GUI components, when would you recommend creating a user thread? I can only think of when you have many frames in your program

Comment: The presentation (GUI) of the application itself deserves a thread. The events are actions in response to user interactions with the screen objects from that presentation: connected but different. Keeping the threads separate improves the responsiveness of any App.